# Ubuntu 14.04 File Server, using Samba, NFS, OwnCloud and SFTP, all on the same mounted path

Tags: 14.04, server, mount, samba, nfs

My Ubuntu 14.04 box has a mounted HDD with ext4 on local the path /Public
I chown the path to my only username so I can transfer files using SFTP (via SFTP client) from my Windows Machine.
I wanted to mount /Public on another Ubuntu server using NFS, but it looks like it doesnt mount unless the owner of /Public on the File Server is nobody.nogroup.
If I change owner to nobody.nogroup then I loose SFTP access.
If I use Samba (so I can access /Public from a Windows machine) same thing, I have to change owner to nobody.nogroup and then I loose access via SFTP)

In essence, Id to have the file server with the /Public path, accessible via SFTP, also mounted on another Ubuntu box using NFS, also accessible on a Windows Box (via Samba), and of course, locally since I intent to install OwnCloud and point the Data path to /Public

If this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` please?

Comment: Please also add your `/etc/exports`.